# Angularjs Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] is showing

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error , can anyone help me find why i am getting this error

```
  angular.min.js:102Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
        at Error (native)
        at https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
        at Sb (https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:19:510)
        at tb 

(https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:20:78)
        at https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:75:331
        at https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:57:65
        at s (https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:408)
        at A (https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:56:443)
        at g (https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:299)
        at g (https://localhost/public/lib/angular/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
```

Comment: did you create module ?

Comment: Did you check the error description at all before posting it here? It clearly explains why you have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your code here. It seems like you missed to create module.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes due to following reason

Either you missed the module

And you added a dependency whose javascript file is not refered

Please check these condition if still not works then share the code